# Drawing stacked bar graphs using \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code from the answer of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457480/drawing-bar-graphs-using-foreach/457485?noredirect=1#comment1150728_457485), Can the bar graphs be drawn as a stacked bar graphs, as shown in the following drawings

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4, transform shape,linecolor/.style={thick,blue}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{1.}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{5}
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (8,0) node [black, xshift=.35cm, yshift=0cm] {Age};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,6) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=.3cm] {Fr.};
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \aff using int(\y*2)]in {1,...,5}{
\draw [linecolor] (.15,\incrmnt*\y) -- +(0:-.3) node [left] {\aff};
}

\foreach \x [evaluate= \x as \aff using int(\inc*\x+20)]in {1,...,6}{
\draw [linecolor] (\incrmnt*\x,.15) -- +(-90:.3) node [below] {\aff};
}

\draw[ybar interval,pattern=north west lines]
plot coordinates{(1,1) (2,4) (3,5) (4,2) (5,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4, transform shape,linecolor/.style={thick,blue}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{1.}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{5}
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (14,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,6);
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \aff using int(\y*2)]in {1,...,5}{
\draw [] (.15,\incrmnt*\y) -- +(0:-.3) node [left] {\aff};
}

\draw[ybar,bar width=2cm,pattern=north west lines]
plot coordinates{(2,3.5)  (7,5.5) (12,2) 
};
\node[below] at (2,0) {Pass};
\node[below] at (7,0) {Good};
\node[below] at (12,0) {V. Good};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: To be honest did't check your code, but maybe https://www.google.com/search?q=barchart+site:tex.stackexchange.com&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj68siJrqneAhULzaQKHVTKDs8QsAR6BAgGEAE will give some points.

Comment: Is the position of these colours determined by data? Otherwise, is it completely random?

Comment: @AndréC These colours are random. Please check my added drawing. Thank you

Comment: I misspoke, is the height of the colored rectangles determined by data? Or are these heights random?

Comment: I'd probably use an `ybar stacked` plot from pgfplots.

Comment: @AndréC The height of the coloured rectangles are random.

Comment: @marmot Thank you. Would you please tell me how to do it.

Comment: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204928/121799) is an example of a stacked ybar plot with a pattern.

Comment: @marmot Yes, I thought about that too. In addition, I'm looking at `ybar interval stacked` but it seems like a dead end. I continue my exploration of the `pgfplots` manual.

Comment: @AndréC. Can the bars begin some distance above the x axis, as the drawing I added to my question; or 2 bars drawn on the same location with different lengths. In that case I can fake the stacked graph by drawing one graph in front of the other one. Because marmot example does not have the flexibility of your code in my previous question. Thank you

Comment: The second graph is the easiest to do, it is done exactly as in the link given by marmot https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204928/138900 The first is feasible with pgfplots and a little bit of DIY. The third is less conventional and deserves a little more research, perhaps using a different package than pgfplots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle of a question and answer site like tex.stackexchange is to ask **only one** question at a time. So, I will only answer the **first** graph. The second one [already having an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204928/138900) whose link has been given to you in a comment by @marmot.

As for the third, it alone deserves a real question based on a real problem with real data. That is, a problem that really arises for you with real data that you really need.

`Tikz` does not have an operation to make such graphics easily. The `pgfplots` package allows you to build them. The disadvantage is that it involves learning a new package with about 600 pages of documentation, which necessarily takes a lot of time.

Note that the loading of the `pgfplots` package must be followed by the version of pgfplots used as `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` (latest version to date). Indeed, it ensures the **backwards compatibility** of the written code with future versions of pgfplots. The code will thus always produce the same result.

The `plot` operation of the tikz package is called `addplot` on pgfplots. This operation can only be performed within an `axis` environment. 
Thus, the code is included in 2 environments: the first `tikzpicture`, the second `axis`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked]
\addplot [fill=green] coordinates{(25,1) (30,4) (35,5) (40,2) (45,0)};
\addplot [fill=cyan] coordinates{(25,1) (30,1) (35,1.5) (40,.5) (45,2)};
\addplot [pattern color=red,draw=black,pattern=north east lines]coordinates{(25,.5) (30,2) (35,1) (40,1) (45,0.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

By default, the graph produced by pgfplot draws twice the abscissa axis (above and below the figure) and the same for the y-axis.

[image: defaulft]

To display it in a conventional way, you must specify in the options:
 `axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left,` .

The minimum coordinates can be specified with the keys `ymin=0,ymax=10,xmin=20,xmax=50,`
The data is represented in a stack with the `ybar stacked` key.

[image: graph-1]

In this graph the bars are centered above the abscissa while you want to place them between the coordinates.
I tried with the `ybar interval stacked` key and it doesn't work. Either I didn't understand how it works, or the package has a bug?

So, to get around this problem, I enlarged the bars with the key `bar width=5` which means that the bars are 5 units wide, the units being those of the abscissa axis.

[image: graph-2]

And to place them in the right place, I moved them to the right by 2.5 units (unit of the abscissa axis) with the key `bar shift=2.5`

The final result is:

[image: final]

The final code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked,
            axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left,
            ymin=0,ymax=10, xmin=20,xmax=50,
            minor y tick num=1,
            bar width=5,
            bar shift=2.5,
]
\addplot [fill=green]coordinates{(25,1) (30,4) (35,5) (40,2) (45,0)};
\addplot [fill=cyan]coordinates{(25,1) (30,1) (35,1.5) (40,.5) (45,2)};
\addplot [pattern color=red,draw=black,pattern=north east lines]coordinates{(25,.5) (30,2) (35,1) (40,1) (45,0.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation. I appreciate them very much.

Comment: @Hany You are welcome:)